# Copy files from one folder to many via Powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to copy the files from one folder to many.  Here's an example of my directory structure:

```
\\files\CA1\Files\Files
```

`CA` = state code
`1` = office in that state

I want to copy all files from a source folder into the last files folder.  The last files folder in that directory structure above is the destination.  The script just needs to cycle through all of the directories with that state code and copy the new files into `\\files\CA*\files\FILES\` folder.  For instance, I want to copy all files from `c:\documents` into all folders that are for `CA`, regardless of the office number.  Here's what I have so far:

```
$source      = 'C:\Documents'
$destination = (Get-ChildItem -Path \\files\CA*\Files\Files -Recurse -Directory)
foreach ($dir in $destination){
Get-ChildItem $dir.Fullname | ForEach-Object {
  $_.FullName
  #Copy-Item -Path $Source -Destination $_ -Force -Recurse -WhatIf
}}
```

Comment: Is `\\files\CA1\Files\Files` always structured as is or may it be more `Files` sublevels ? Do you want copy on each `Files` level or only the depthest ?

Comment: I am not clear on what is going wrong with your code?